# Loading custom fonts failure

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

So I was trying to load a new font with CSS3's `@font-face`, but it wasn't working.
Here is my code:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url('styles/LucidaGrande.ttf');
}

/* [...] */

@media screen and (max-width: 5500px) {
    #title{
        font-size:50px;
        font-family: myFirstFont;
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple formats, not every browser supports the `truetype font` format. Put your file into the [font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and you get all the information that is needed to get this work in every browser: Firefox 3.5+; Opera 10+; Safari 3.1+; Chrome 4.0.249.4+; Internet Explorer 4+; iPad; iPhone.

If it doesn't solve the problem, please provide more information about the browser, ect. and give us a live example.